Covering automorphisms of the universal cover of a flat torus are translations - proof by a group extension
Let $(\tilde{M},\pi,M)$ be the universal Riemannian covering of $M$. I know that $M$ is biholomorphic to the quotient of $\tilde{M}$ by the covering automorphisms. If we take $M$ to be a flat torus, then $\tilde{M}$ by the uniformization theorem is biholomorphic to $\mathbb C$ and the covering automorphisms are a subgroup of $\mathbb C$ automorphisms. It can be shown that freeness and proper discontinuity of that action implies that the covering automorphisms are generated by two translations.
I've seen that the problem can be restated in terms of metrics and instead of working with automorphisms of $\mathbb C$ we claim the covering automorphisms to be a discrete subgroup of the Euclidean plane isometries, isomorphic to torus' fundamental group which is $\mathbb Z^2$, so we have a monomorphism $\mathbb Z^2 \rightarrow Iso(\mathbb R^2)$. As plane isometries are an extension of orthogonal linear transformations $O(2)$ by translations, the fact that there is no monomorphism $\mathbb Z^2 \rightarrow O(2)$ such that its image is discrete, should somehow imply that the image of $\mathbb Z^2 \rightarrow Iso(\mathbb R^2)$ is contained in translations, but I don't understand how it works.
The nonexistence of a monomorphism $\mathbb Z^2 \rightarrow O(2)$ is clear to me. There is no monomorphisms even from $\mathbb Z$ as the image of 2, which is always a rotation, is either periodic, so not a monomorphism, or it is a rotation by $2\pi \alpha$, where $\alpha$ is irrational and such image is not discrete.
I thought that if we assumed such a monomorphism $\mathbb Z^2 \rightarrow Iso(\mathbb R^2)$ might send one of generators to an isometry other than translation, then its composition with projection $Iso(\mathbb R^2) \rightarrow O(2)$ somehow induces a monomorphism $\mathbb Z^2 \rightarrow O(2)$ but the projection is far from preserving monomorphisms under such composition.
I believe that the result can be again shown using plane's geometry but I'm particularly interested in how the fact that plane isometries form such group extension can be applied.
I tag it with "riemannian-geometry" but it is rather motivation for the problem than its field so I would appreciate suggestions on tags.
